# Simple way to create a slideshow with Twig and a for loop?

Tags: templating, forloop

I have this code, which is basically a loop in a Twig template where I show opinions:

```
<section class="opinions">
    <h2 class="opinions__title heading2">
        Opiniones de otros guardianes
    </h2>
    <ul class=" row md-12 center-md">
        <li class="col md-3">
        {% for opinion in opiniones %}
            <blockquote class="opinion__blq simple-bubble text-large">
                {{ opinion.opinion }}
            </blockquote>
            <p>
                {{ opinion.autor }}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{ opinion.ciudad }}
            </p>
        {% endfor %}
        </li>
    </div>
</section>
```

I'd like to create a simple slideshow to show these 3 opinions. I've tried with diferent methods but they don't work. Does someone know a simple, easy way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't really have anything to do with Craft CMS

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a Craft question. Craft is simply responsible for outputting the requested data into your template, and you can use whatever you'd like on the front end to display it.

What you want in this case is a JavaScript carousel or slider. You can build your own, or use a simple library. I like [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) and use it often, but if you just do a Google search for "javascript carousel" you'll find tons of options to choose from. If you're using a specific library or framework for your site, you might want to include that like "javascript carousel bootstrap" or "javascript carousel react" to find something that leverages libraries you're already loading.